# Hide implementation in header-only library

Tags: c++, header-only

I've tried to use an implementation namespace, but when i 'using namespace' it, it pulls in the whole implementation namespace, rendering it useless.

```
namespace library {
 namespace implementation {
  //implementation
 }

 using namespace implementation

 //visible identifiers
}
```

Is there way to hide implementation, without needing to use "implementation::" before using anything from implementation?

Comment: Don't use `using namespace implementation;`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> rendering it useless

Well, it's not useless, you just can't `using namespace` it. You have to explicitly prepend `implementation::` to the names in it. For this reason, it might make sense to choose a shorter name (`detail` is commonly used in c++ projects for this purpose).

Also, I'd like to point out that header-only and implementation hiding are two somewhat conflicting requirements. If you truly need to hide the implementation, you can't go header-only.

Comment: Ok, then i'll use macros (which i'll undef at the end of the header) to prepend identifiers from implementation.

Comment: @G_glop it's your code, but I don't see an advantage of using a macro for this.

Comment: Just a thought, maybe only for some widely used types.